# Warm spot on Roof + Attic Rotting

Tags: insulation, roof, soffit, winter

I had a contractor come in (**failed the DIY part :(**) and inspect the roof.  He suspects that the ice melter is bad and the moisture is coming from the bathroom exhaust fan.  He fixed the holes and added some aluminum to cover the hole.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the flashing from when it was replaced in the summer.

[image: Flashing]

Thank you here is an update PLEASE HELP!!!

It was narrow inside and here are the best pictures I could get.

[image: Roof near Warm Spot]
[image: Roof near Warm Spot 2]

Here is something more alarming.

[image: Exhaust]

Pink is the bathroom exhaust and silver is a fireplace.
Note:  There was no bathroom exhaust installed, but there was the insulated pink vent.  We installed a bathroom vent in the summer and connected it to the existing vent.  I touched some of the black wood and it is actually wet.  The insulation below seemed wet as well.

[image: Insulation]
[image: Rotting Wood]

[image: Roof]

First winter in home.  Any concerns or fixes?  Do I need to clear some soffit? Add more insulation?

Previous owner did have heating elements along that edge.  I have not turned it on.

I did notice that there is some paint peeling/crumbling on the ceiling (close to) that area inside the house. (Could be unrelated)

[image: ceiling closet]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably some airflow/leakage from inside the house, making that spot warmer.  You need to crawl into the attic and see what's going on there.

Comment: Would check the attic in that area.  Hard to tell from the picture, but looks like a stain on the ceiling, which might from a roof leak.  Wet insulation is almost useless to keep heat in.

Comment: At that position there will be no room in the attic,

Comment: Consider whether you need to install some soffit and/or ridge vents.

Comment: From recently updated inside photos of bathroom and fireplace vents, looks like the dark (wet/stained) wood is all downhill of the two vent openings. I strongly suspect water is leaking in around one or both vents. Some of the wet roof sheathing looks like it might already be rotting.

Comment: @User160423 - Generally, you don't want to edit someone's answer or add to it.  The changes you were suggesting belong in a comment under the answer.

Comment: @Armand  It looks like you were right.  Is there anything I can do for the rot? or am I just looking at replacing the roof in the summer?

Comment: @user160423 The first thing is to stop the leaking, even if only until spring when you can do a proper fix. At that time, best to have someone who knows roofs examine the flashing of the vents from above and below, look at the sheathing from below and evaluate how much life is left in your shingles. You may only need to have a section of sheathing replaced and that area reshingled. Decades ago when we had our house reshingled, we paid the modest extra cost for thicker 50-year-guarantee asphalt shingles and have been happy with how they have lasted - something to consider if you need to reroof.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the angle in the outside roof photo, but it looks like the metal collar for the fireplace is not installed correctly.  The top part of the flange needs to be under the top row of shingles, and the bottom of the flange needs to rest on top of the bottom shingles.  It looks like the bottom flange is under the shingles, which would explain the roof leak down slope from the fireplace vent.

[image]

This is the way a properly flashed roof penetration should look.  Picture is from https://profengineering.com.  Note that there are tons of references on the web on how to properly flash such a pipe that penetrates the roof.

[image]

Finally, the circular spot of melted snow near the gutter is "normal" if you have an air register for heating that comes out of the ceiling below that spot. The hot air can leak out of the register boot and/or heat can just radiate from the duct at that point that warms the roof in that area.  I have pictures like that of my roof.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is a bit more relieving.  I thought it was just bigger and compared it to the neighbor's roof.  I think that answered my original question.  As for the flashing, I did get the roof inspected when I moved in, and he replaced the flashing.  I found more pics from the summer. (In the original post)