# Water running down beam

Tags: roof, leak, attic, beam

Water is leaking and running down a beam and is collecting collecting near the bedroom.  I can't fix the leak right now.

Is there any way I can temporarily stop the water from flowing down the beam? Even if it is temporary?

Please help.

[Pictures for reference in previous post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/262870/warm-spot-on-roof-attic-rotting)

Comment: a question must stand on its own, without reference to another question

Comment: Come uplo with a kluges to divert the water further up the beam? There isn't a standard patch for a problem which shouldn't be allowed to occur in the first place.

Comment: VTC: This question can not be answered with the information supplied. What is the source of the water? What beam are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Staple one end of a towel to the beam. Drape the other end of the towel into a bucket. Empty the bucket as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Source of water? Roof leak? Roof leak while it's wet requires the expensive stuff at the store that specifically says it will seal a leak when wet